# bash array of file locations - how to find last updated file?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, timestamp

Have an array of files built from a locate command that I need to cycle through and figure out the latest and print the latest. We have a property file called randomname-properties.txt that is in multiple locations and is sometimes called randomname-properties.txt.bak or randomname-properties.txt.old.  Example is below

Directory structure

```
/opt/test/something/randomname-properties.txt
/opt/test2/something/randomname-properties.txt.old
/opt/test3/something/randomname-properties.txt.bak
/opt/test/something1/randomname-properties.txt.working
```

Code

```
#Builds list of all files 
PropLoc=(`locate randomname-properties.txt`)
#Parse list and remove older file
for i in ${PropLoc[@]} ; do
  if [ ${PropLoc[0]} -ot ${PropLoc[1]} ] ; then
    echo "Removing ${PropLoc[0]} from the list as it is older"
    #Below should rebuild the array while removing the older element
    PropLoc=( "${PropLoc[@]/$PropLoc[0]}" )
  fi
done
echo "Latest file found is ${PropLoc[@]}"
```

Overall this isn't working. It currently appears that it doesn't even go into the loop as the first two files have the same timestamp of last year (doesn't appear to deconflict down past the day for things older than a year). Any thoughts on how to get this to work properly? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ls -t`, which will sort the files by modification time. The first line will then be the newest file.

```
newest=$(ls -t "${PropLoc[@]}" | head -n 1)
```

This should work as long as none of the filenames contain newlines.

Don't forget to quote your variables in case they contain whitespace or wildcard characters.

Answer (score 1):

Without parsing the output of `ls`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

latest=

while read -r -d '' file; do
  if [ "$file" -nt "$latest" ]; then
    latest=$file
  fi
done < <(locate --null randomname-properties.txt)

printf 'Latest file found is %s\n' "$latest"
```